# Vim stops scrolling randomly in terminal?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

Usually I can scroll in vim when I open a file in the mac terminal.

However, recently, all of a sudden sometimes I am not able to.

When I go to scroll, instead the entire terminal scrolls so I see what I had previously typed in the shell.

How can I fix this?

This is new, I've been using vim for months and it has only started to happen now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably messed with the `mouse` setting.

```
:help mouse-using
```